# URL rewrite parameter lost (add_rewrite_rule)

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

This is definitely not the first question regarding the issue. I have read a lot and tried, even more, but without success.

I want to do the following: rewrites URLs
from: example.com/**cars/lambo**
to: example.com/index.php?p=42&**model=lambo**

The **p** parameter corresponds to a fixed *page* ID I have created.

I have a custom plugin in which I use the `plugins_loaded` hook to load the method `setupFrontendRewrites` from my `CarUrlRewrite` class.

The class looks like that:

```
class CarUrlRewrite{
    const regex = 'cars/(.+?)/?$';
    const param = 'model';
    const pageId = 42;

    // this method is called with the plugins_loaded hook
    public static function setupFrontendRewrites(){ 
        add_action('wp_loaded', array(__CLASS__, 'flushRulesIfNecessary'));
        add_filter('query_vars', array(__CLASS__, 'addQueryVariables'));
        add_action('init', array(__CLASS__, 'rewriteRules'));
        add_action('template_redirect', array(__CLASS__, 'rewriteCatchesToInjectContent'));
    }

    public static function flushRulesIfNecessary(){
        $wpRewriteRules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );
        if (!isset($wpRewriteRules[self::regex])){ // if my regex is missing, flush rules!
            global $wp_rewrite;
            $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
        }
    }

    public static function addQueryVariables($vars){
        $vars[] = self::param;
        return $vars; // this is a filter after all
    }

    public static function rewriteRules() {
        // from: example.com/cars/lambo
        // into: example.com/index.php?p=42&model=lambo
        add_rewrite_rule(
            self::regex,
            'index.php?p='.self::pageId.'&'.self::param.'=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );
    }

    // Catch the URL and redirect it to a template file
    public static function rewriteCatchesToInjectContent() {
        global $wp_query; 
        $model = array_key_exists('model', $wp_query->query_vars) ? $wp_query->query_vars['model'] : null;
        // would expect to see the model parameter filled here, but don't :-(
        // do something with the model variable
    }
}
```

I did some `error_log` outputs to see that all class methods get called.

What is happening is that the rewrite works in that it forwards me to the page (page ID 42).
The URL is then **example.com/myslug**
(where **myslug** is the permalink from the page). There is no **model** parameter however.
What I need is **example.com/myslug?model=lambo**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The URL is then **example.com/myslug** (where **myslug** is the
> permalink from the page). There is no **model** parameter however.

That happens because *you used the wrong parameter for the Page ID*:

> The **p** parameter corresponds to a fixed *page* ID I have created.

So actually, for the `page` post type, i.e. Pages, you should use **`page_id`** and not `p`. See the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters) for more details.

So you just need to replace the `index.php?p=` with `index.php?page_id=` and your rewrite rule will work correctly, but remember to flush the rewrite rules manually via the Permalink Settings admin page. (Simply visit the page and WordPress will automatically flush the rules without you having to click the Save Changes button)

Comment: OMG that was the problem! Thank you sooo much!

Comment: Glad I could help! (PS: I revised my answer - I changed the 1st paragraph to the correct *quoted text* )